# ¿Como convertir los números negativos de un array integer en positivos? (Java)

Tags: java, array

```js
/*
* Mi proposito era usar Math.abs(a) para luego usar Arrays.sort(a)
* La pregunta es si en una linea sin necesidad de usar un for puedo 
* convertir todos los numeros negativos del array en positivos para
* poder ordenarlo bien. Mi idea era hacer: Arrays.sort(Math.abs(a));
*/
public static void arrayANumerosPositivos(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; a < a.length; i++) {
          a[i] = Math.abs(a[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(a);
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe, por favor revisa [help] y [faq]. Puedes mirar de usar Streams en Java 8: https://www.arquitecturajava.com/programacion-funcional-java-8-streams/. En todo caso, y aunque saber streams es conveniente, "hacerlo en una sola línea" no debería ser un objetivo si complica leer el código. Y si no me crees, mira como queda: `for (int i = 0; a < a.length; i++) {a[i] = Math.abs(a[i]);} Arrays.sort(a);`, que es completamente legal. Voto para cerrar, si tienes algún problema específico jugando con streams haz una pregunta que no parezca tanto "por favor escribidme el código".

Comment: Su pregunta no se refiere a escribir el código en una linea. Está muy claro en su pregunta (y con el ejemplo) que lo que pregunta es si existe una "sentencia" que realice la misma función que el bucle.